кто знает, объясните почему значения не добавляются в переменную
blue, green = map(int, input().split())

black = green*2
red = green*4

pens = [blue,green,black,red]
res = 0
for i in pens:
    res + i
print(res)


res + i - что вы хотите чтобы получилось?

что бы все значения из списка pens суммировались в переменной res

Чтобы значение добавлялось в переменную, нужно использовать присваивание. А сейчас вы просто складываете два числа, и результат никак не используете.

Вы бы лучше python хоть чуть-чуть поизучали, прежде чем на форумы идти...

res + i - это просто операция. Чтобы изменить значение переменной надо присвоить ей новое значение.
Верно: res = res + i или res += i
